# Debian: Remove all packages installed during a specific date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, uninstall, package-management

On a specific day, I installed lots of packages - that I didn't keep a good track of - on my Debian machine. Now I need to remove all this mess, because what I was trying to install simply didn't work at the end.

So I used this modified command

```
grep "2015-12-19.*.install " /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d: -f1 | sudo apt autoremove -y
```

I got from [this similar Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548683/how-can-one-remove-all-packages-installed-after-a-certain-date-time). However, it doesn't seem to be removing all of the packages.

***Is the used command above correct? Or which other command should I use?***

Answer (score 2):

The answer on AskUbuntu is fine, but in your case you need to use `xargs` and `remove` instead of `autoremove`:

```
grep "2015-12-19.*.install " /var/log/dpkg.log | \
awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sudo apt remove -y
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'll try that and let you know.